# Retrieve from the database rows ordered by a boolean column, but also random as a second criterion

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-10

I have an Items table:

```
id | name | is_featured
1    name1       false
```

The items from this table I need to show them in a random way, but is_featured first. The rules are:

1. If count `is_featured=True` > 6, get `is_featured=True` all, and randomize and get first 6
2. If count `is_featured=True` < 6, get `is_featured=True` all, and randomize
   Count how many are missing up to 6. Get from non-featured random the remaining items.Unite lists.

I do this in 2-3 steps in database:

- first count the number of featured
- first get featured then get the rest if is needed, and randomize(in backend)

It is possible to do that in one step, in database?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want six rows, with the `is_featured` first.  You can do this in one step:

```
select i.*
from items i
order by i.is_featured desc,  -- true is first
         random()
fetch first 6 rows only;
```

That is, sort all the data with `is_featured` first.  Then choose the first six.